# Let be $\Omega$ the bounded region by the curves $y=\sqrt{x}$, $y=2x$, and $y=4$. Determine the area of the region $\Omega$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

I need help with this exercise. I want to know if I'm establishing the integrals correctly.

Let be $\Omega$ the bounded region by the curves $y=\sqrt{x}$, $y=2x$, and $y=4$. Determine the area of the region $\Omega$.

I did the graph with Desmos and this is what I believe is $\Omega$: the purple and the blue shaded regions.

I'm dividing the whole region in 4 subregions and I'm calculating the area for each region.

This is what I have:

$$A=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{4}}(4-\sqrt{x})dx+\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{2}(4-2x)dx+\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{2}(2x-\sqrt{x})dx+\int_{2}^{16}(4-\sqrt{x})dx$$

I'm not sure if this is correct, I will appreciate in advance your help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I think your understanding of $\Omega$ is incorrect. $\Omega$ is only the blue region. This leaves you with only the $2$ last integrals which seem to be correct.

Comment: @HappyDay I saw my error. Thanks so much.